# Bing Image Search API

Tags: javascript, image, api, limit, bing

Does anyone know if Bing limits the number of requests an application can have for the Image Search API? I looked through the terms and couldn't find anything but the wording that they 'reserve' the right to do so. My application would pull several images for each user - so there could potentially be a lot of requests. Any feedback?

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether this is actually enforced but the guidelines say

> "[You must] Restrict your usage to
>   less than 7 queries per second (QPS)
>   per IP address. You may be permitted
>   to exceed this limit under some
>   conditions, but this must be approved
>   through discussion with
>   api_tou@microsoft.com."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440746.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response! Excellent, that's very generous of them actually

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is possible that this guide contains outdated information about restrictions. There are no info about queries number in the current version of terms (ver. March 2011). At the same time, there is a line about restricted advertisment on the page where the bing images or videos results are situated - this is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Free Bing Search API is limited to 5000 Transactions/month & the Source type can be..

```
Web
Images
News
Videos
Related Search
Spelling Suggestions
```

More Info, https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44